# Build and Load a simple Angular2 app in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, angular, loading

I have a app already built in Angular2, say a basic app. When I use that with Cordova and build it for android... the build installs in the system (the debug build) but stops at loading... stage. What other things do I need to ensure my ES5 code is initializing boot.js correctly.

I have tried adding the device plugin and altered the code as well like this, but not been able to build past the loading screen.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
}
```

Any help is welcome.

Note: `cordova emulate browser` works

**UPDATE 2**

My HTML FILE without

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/skins/skin-white.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main-app>
      <div class="app">
          <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
          <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
              <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </main-app>
    <head>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/system.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/http.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is what is happening. When I add  I get errors for all files like angular2, css, etc not found. If I remove the  then the first page loads and when I try to browse to a route this is the error I get... I am not able to map to the actual template path of the router.

[image]

The following is the source of how it is rendered.

[image]

**UPDATE 3**
Error I am getting for child of a parent route (nested route)
[image]

Comment: There is no <base href="./">  in your index.html. Please notice the dot on the path.

Comment: @Abdulrahman - Great... it worked. Now I am able to traverse through all the parent route (1st level). But for the child of routes (2nd Level) it gives the above error - update 3

Comment: do you have multiple <router-outlet></router-outlet> in the same template? because you can't have more than one  <router-outlet> in one template

Comment: @Abdulrahman No. I have mainroute(router-outlet) [/..] -> many routes with one child route[/..] -> child route(router-outlet) -> many routes (this route is where I am getting an error)

Comment: Does the issue exist also on the browser? If so, I suggest opening a new questing with your routing details, i.e. RouteConfig & router-outlet.

Comment: @Abdulrahman Yes it does. I will open a new question.

Comment: @Abdulrahman - can you check this new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016993/exception-error-during-instantiation-of-t-primary-outlet-already-registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referencing the function *onDeviceReady* before declaring it. Try moving the function declaration before adding the event listener.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: No... still the same. The emulator says connection to file://..../index.html was reset then if you open the app manually it stops at loading stage.

Comment: do I need to change the platform/browser or something. I read this in the api docs but not well documented.

Comment: @Gary Angular2 still has only one platform, so there is no need to change anything for now. Would you please post your index.html ?

Comment: Update index.html. Please check.

Comment: @Gary In you index.html, you are referencing files from external source. You will have to add the hosts to whitelist [https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist](cordova-plugin-whitelist) or download the files in a local directory

Comment: @Gary I created a very basic angular2 app with cordova in this [repo](https://github.com/abuda7em/angular2_cordova), clone it, add the android platform and run it. I tried to make it as close to your config.

Comment: Thanks that worked for the initial app. Does router (nested routing) have a problem working with android? I am getting error `EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of t!.BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23597
angular2.dev.js:23597 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Primary outlet is already registered.` when debugging with emulate browser

Comment: I have some css also taking fonts from network and the css also has issues. What do I need to do to avoid css fetch issues from the network.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106145/discussion-between-gary-and-abdulrahman).

Comment: @Gary as for the css, you either need to add the url to white list in config.xml [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist), or you can download the file and save in css folder for example. About the route, I committed new update on the repo with sample route. As for the chat, I am there :)

Comment: I tried the debugging, seems like even after building and the apk having one component, the apk is unable to load it and the chrome inspector is showing a blank file.

Comment: @Gary it's very hard to tell, would you please update your question with your progress on the debugging. Any errors on the inspector console?

Comment: I have updated the debugging and related errors in Update 2. Please have a look once. It seems to be pathing issue.