# "Exception: Error during instantiation of t! Primary outlet already registered." in cordova angular2 app

Tags: android, cordova, angular, router

I am building an simple cordova app with my project. It has 2 levels of nesting (main route) -> child route -> (another child route). `When trying to browse to the 2nd level (another child route)` I get an error saying `Exception: Error during instantiation of t! Primary outlet already registered.` First level works fine. I have not used router outlet twice in any template. The issue is the same in the emulation of browser as well as android.

Attached the chrome inspect below.

[image]

My HTML File

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="./">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/skins/skin-white.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main-app>
      <div class="app">
          <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
          <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
              <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </main-app>
    <head>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/system.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angulardeps/2.0.0-beta.9/http.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

My build source structure:
[image]

My main component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ApproutesComponent} from '../app/approutes';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';

@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/d/...', component: ApproutesComponent, name: 'ApproutesCmp', useAsDefault:true}
])
@Component({
  selector: 'main-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/r/main/rmain.html',
  directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class RroutesComponent {
  constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the most important part... the code... is it reproducible in a plnkr using cordova? I know nothing about it, but your issue is with the router.

Comment: Yes the code runs on a server correctly. Its when I emulate or build with Cordova I get the error. Its a router error.

Comment: Can you provide main-app component  code?

Comment: @sasikumar-d-r I have updated with the main-app component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem with angular2 beta11, just not using cordova.

According to a post [here](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-authentication-sample/issues/58) **you should use the non-minified version of router.js**.
Sounds strange, but it worked for me.

Comment: In addition, I had to use the non-minified version of Angular 2 as well: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.14/angular2.js`

Comment: How do you specify to use the non minified verion when using webpack and NPM?