# angular2 routing is not allowing some grand child to rout back to the grand parent

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Unable to rout to grand parent from a grand child. The intended hierarchy is

> Main -> Branch1 --> Branch2 --> Branch1 --> Child1;

this is not working.
There is also a

> Branch1 --> Branch1

recursion which works fine.

```
import { enableProdMode, Component, Input, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter } from 'angular2/core';
import { Router, RouteParams, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({ 
template:`
  <h1>Leaf2</h1>
`,
  }
) 
export class Leaf2Component { }

@Component({ 
template:`
  <h1>Leaf1</h1>
`,
 }
) 
export class Leaf1Component { }

@Component({ 
template:`
  <h1>Branch</h1>
  <a [routerLink]="['./Child2']">Child2</a>
  <!--<a [routerLink]="['./Branch1/Child1']">Child2</a>-->
  <div>30</div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <div>31</div>
`,
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
 }
) 
@RouteConfig([
{ path: '/child2', name: 'Child2', component: Leaf1Component, useAsDefault: true },
//{ path: '/branch1/...', name: 'Branch1', component: Branch1Component       },
 ])
export class Branch2Component { }

@Component({ 
template:`
  <h1>Branch</h1>
  <a [routerLink]="['./Child1']">Child1</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['./Child2']">Child2</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['./Branch1']">My Branch1</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['../Branch1']">Parent Branch1</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['./Branch2']"My >My Branch2</a>
  <div>20</div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <div>21</div>
`,
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
 }
) 
 @RouteConfig([
{ path: '/child1', name: 'Child1', component: Leaf1Component, useAsDefault: true },
{ path: '/child2', name: 'Child2', component: Leaf2Component },
{ path: '/branch1/...', name: 'Branch1', component: Branch1Component },
{ path: '/branch2/...', name: 'Branch2', component: Branch2Component },
])
export class Branch1Component { }

@Component({
selector: 'app', 
template:`
  <h1>Main</h1>
  <a [routerLink]="['./Branch1']">Branch1</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['Child2']">Child2</a>
  <div>10</div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <div>11</div>
`,
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
 }
) 
@RouteConfig([
{ path: '/branch1/...', name: 'Branch1', component: Branch1Component },
{ path: '/child2', name: 'Child2', component: Leaf2Component },
])
export class MainComponent { }

enableProdMode();
bootstrap(MainComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

If you un-comment the commented lines above, the following error occurs.

```
angular2.dev.js:23730 EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of Router! 

angular2.dev.js:23730 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Route config should contain exactly one "component", "loader", or "redirectTo" property.
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you using the minified version of router file?

Comment: @Gary I use it through npm, as in angular2 quick start, 2.0.0-beta.12 (as in my package.json file). Is that minified?

Comment: Not sure. It has both. What is the script tag you are using for router? is it router.min.js or router.js? I had similar issue and it got resolve by using non-minified version of router. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016993/exception-error-during-instantiation-of-t-primary-outlet-already-registered

Comment: Can you also specify component selector tags for all the components and see if the error goes away that could also be the issue. Seems selectors are the issue.

Comment: @Gary 
1. Yes, I set selector tags to each, but the same problem persists.
2. Oh, in my index.html the script tags were "node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js". As said, straight off quick start tutorial. So I changed to "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.15/router.js"
3. I also upgraded to beta15, but still the same problem persists.

Comment: hmm... Ok. try this. There seems to be a loop for Branch1Cmp try changing that to a valid new component and see if this works. This error comes when a component is not defined for a routeconfig

Comment: As said, Branch1 --> Branch1 recursion is already working. It is only the  Branch1 --> Branch2 --> Branch1 , mutual recursion that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

- Branch paths were a little different (else gives branch not found error)
- Component selector specification was not needed but could have been better
- `router.min.js was giving the error. Usage of router.js resolved the issue you were facing. This was your issue. The error comes when a component is not mapped to RouterConfig`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hROril?p=preview

Comment: Angular `xxx.**min**.js` are generally broken AFAIK.

Comment: True. Not nice will be difficult to manage load times. Router is small but angular fike broken will become difficult

Comment: @Gary, your plnkr is using parent route (['../Branch1/Child1']), which, as mentioned above (Parent Branch1 link) is working fine. The problem is only when I un-comment these two lines above. Basically I want the grand parent component to be a child component with different data. Since recursion is working already, why angular2 is raising an issue here? So, the question is, why I should not un-comment the two lines (one in template and another in routeconfig of Branch2Component) in my sample?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. The plunkr has a working section un-commented lines. if you want other routes use other route but right ones or new ones with your other data etc. It works with router.js and not router.min.js.

Comment: You cannot have a non-terminal routes ending for sure. It has to end somewhere

Comment: Main -> Branch1 --> Branch2 --> Branch1 --> Child1
This does end, I guess. This is what is expected.

Comment: Simply put, if you use my original code in plnkr, it will work, but if you uncomment the two commented lines there, it is not working. Is my question clear?

Comment: commented section `//{ path: '/branch1/...', name: 'Branch1', component: Branch1Component},` will not work. Its a non-terminal route needs to end with terminal route. Other I have uncommented in the plnkr and is working

Comment: Why is it a 'non-terminal' route? If you see Branch1, I can create as many as I want, interminably, and that just works. With Branch2 I'm just trying to fork that recursion and continue looping. Why is that not allowed, is the core question.

Comment: this is an incomplete route (a non-terminal route). https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#router-link

Comment: `<a [routerLink]="['./Branch1/Child1']">Child2</a>`
When I link to it I do terminate it with a terminal route, namely "Child1" here (sorry for the wrong text inside the tag). A routeconfig will always specify the link with "/...", so that is not incomplete by itself. So can we not say it is not incomplete either?

Comment: Yes I checked it in the plunkr before. I believe its because its not in the dom. You will face hr sane problem with other links not therr in dom. You might want to try namespace links rather than urls and if that works. Else for url based paths it might not work

Comment: @Gary Not clear about many things you said. How do you say 'it is not in DOM'? I did add that component in the routeconfig, like the other links there. What are 'namespace links' (I tried searching)?

Comment: You can go back not forward (unavailable links) in url. If its possible I have not seen the documentation. You can raise a github issue with angular team. try `[routerLink]="['Branch1Cmp','Child1Cmp']"  instead of path [routerLink]="['../Branch1/Child1']"` and see if it works.